# How to copy one array to another using offsets and clipping?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array used for the player's current sight. 'A' means Actor, or Player in this case.

```
// Sight with depth of 3
char sight[] = { 
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, // 0-6
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, // 7-13
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, // 14-20
    0, 0,  0, 'A', 0, 0, 0, // 21-27
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, // 28-34
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, // 35-41
    0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0  // 42-48
};
```

I'm loading in this custom map file. W = Wall, D = Door, . = Floor

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W.W.D.........WW
W.W.WWWWW.WWW.WW
W...WWWWW...W.D.
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Okay, so I would like to copy this array into the current sight using an offset. If the player is at position (1,1), the x offset is 1, and the y offset is 1. Likewise, if the player is at position (5,4), the x offset is 5 and the y offset is 4. In this case, he is at position (1,1).

No matter where the player is, his sight array has him at the center. So, how can I copy the map array into his sight array using offsets and clipping?

Comment: Show the code you're using now, and explain where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to copy the array? You don't need a copy of the data to obtain the information, just a function that is able to return the offset given the player position, for example:

```
class Player {
  ...
  int getX() const { return x; }
  int getY() const { return y; }
}

class Map {
  ...
  char getWithOffset(const Player& player, int dx, int dy) const {
    return map[player.getX()+dx][player.getY()+dy];
  }
}
```

Then you can call for example

```
map.getWithOffset(player, -1, -1)
```

and obtain the desired delta position according to the player.

If you really want a separate array, from this function you can easily build one, something like:

```
char sight[SIGHT_DEPTH][SIGTH_DEPTH];

int baseX = player.getX() - SIGHT_DEPTH / 2; // start from -3,-3
int baseY = player.getY() - SIGHT_DEPTH / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < SIGHT_DEPTH; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < SIGHT_DEPTH; ++j)
    sight[i][j] = map.getAt(baseX + i, baseY + j);
```

Comment: I have a similar function called peek(). You can check what's north, south, etc. from the player. However, this is just returning one cell. 
What I end up having to do is the following: c = map.peek(m_x, m_y,    EDir_N); sight[N] = c;   Then I have to do that 20+ times. It seems there's an easier way to do this, such as copying the array using deltas/offsets.

Comment: Because you are using peek by specifying a direction, but nothing prevents you from using a numeric offset (and define `EDir_N` as `{0,-1}` for example, so that it goes up by 1 cell.)

Comment: I can see the use of deltas would be easier to put in as arguments. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to loop with this (didn't see your update earlier):  
        int x_center = 3;
 int y_center = 3;

 for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
 {
  for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
  {
   sight[y * 7 + x] = map.peek(m_x, m_y, x - x_center, y - y_center);
  }
 }
   Works really nice! Thanks.